# Об объекте None на выводе функции

Tags: python, функции

```
def dristna(k):
    s = 0
    value = 1.0/k
    s+=value
for h in range(1,5):
    print(dristna(h))
```

На выводе None. При отображении исполнении кода, функция исправно считает все переменные, то return value None. Почему? спасибо

Comment: Ну вы же ничего из функции не возвращаете, а если функция ничего не возвращает то это `None`.  Все логично.

Comment: def dristna(k): возвращает None, вы печатаете print(dristna(h)) это... добавьте return s

Answer (score 2):

Возвращайте значение `s` из функции с помощью оператора `return`.

***Пример:***

```py
def dristna(k):
    s = 0
    value = 1.0 / k
    s += value
    return s         # Если не написать return, функция вернёт None


for h in range(1, 5):
    print(dristna(h))
```

---

**P.S:** Достаточно было написать так:

```py
def dristna(k):
    return 1.0 / k
```